# Handle "504 Gateway Time-out error" via php curl

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-504

I am scraping data for many items via php curl, But for few items, the target website send  "504 Gateway Time-out nginx" error, I have no problem with that, But the main problem is it halted the whole script, So script stops after this error and don't scrape next items,

I just wanna ignore(handle) that error, So that it doesn't halt the script.

This link can be helpful to understand the question https://serverfault.com/questions/882421/504-gateway-time-out-nginx-on-apache-server/882431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 504) {
    /* Handle 504 here. */
} else {
    /* Process data */
}

curl_close($handle);
```

Comment: Awesome, I am gonna try this

Comment: Sure, i am trying to figure out how i can implement this on multi curl request,but i think it is the right solution for the asked question, thanks:)

Comment: i've tried something similar but it does not really catch the error

i still get:

<html><body><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
The server didn't respond in time.
</body></html>