# How do I capture a 504 error in PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-504

I have the CURL request below, and it is returning a 504 error. I want to echo out the fact that it is timing out to the UI, right now the UI isn't notified, but the Chrome console is. Is there a way I can grab the 504 and drop it in an if statement:

```
if ($error == 504) {
    // tell the UI it timed out
} else {
    // report the response
}
```

Right now I am using:

```
curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)
```

but it doesn't seem to grab the 504, probably because there was no response.

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60000,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAgent,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic xxx'
    ),
));
```

Comment: If there's no response, where would the 504 error code come from?

Comment: `504` is `Gateway Timeout`. It comes from a proxy that gets a timeout when it tries to connect to the target server. It's not the error when the original connection gets a timeout.

Comment: curl_exec($curl) is not returning anything, it echos as empty, but I get a 504 in the javascript console.

Comment: The browser is synthesizing that in the console, it's not a real error code.

Comment: So maybe set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT higher and wat for an HTTP response?

Comment: I set the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to 120000 but I get the browser 504 after about 15 seconds.

Comment: Use `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle "504 Gateway Time-out error" via php curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180816/handle-504-gateway-time-out-error-via-php-curl)

Answer (score 0):

> curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)....but it doesn't seem to grab the 504

Barmar suggested that this question is a duplicate of PHP curl timeout error detection hpwever that describes a timeout implemented on the HTTP client - if you specifically want to get the timeout from the gateway/proxy you need to wait a bit longer (assuming it is online).

Most likely your [default_socket_timeout](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) is shorter than the timeout on the proxy. PHP is terminating the Curl call before it gets a response from the remote end. If unset, the default_socket_timeout is 60 seconds. Do beware that most browsers will timeout at 5 minutes after the initial HTTP request.

Comment: Hey, so I have the timeout set to 60 seconds, I have tried 90 and 120 too. I am getting the 504 error in the javascript console, but my question is when that arrived, how do I detect that with PHP, so I can pass it to the UI and say "it timed out"?

Comment: Because right now the spinner in the UI just keeps spinning. I want to stop it and say "timeout" is there some value I can capture to pass in the AJAX response?

Comment: If you've increased your timeout to greater than the value you measured when you tested this directly with a browser then either there is a problem in your code or the site you are trying to retrieve content from is behaving differently with your Curl request. Maybe it's anti-leech mechanism.

Comment: So the use case is the remote endpoint isn't responding, but the developer says it is. My client is complaining so I built a UI so he can push a button and see it not work. I am trying to have the UI say "it timed out" when a timeout response is received.

Comment: I get 504 in Postman too.

Comment: Maybe Barmar was right and you're asking the XY Problem.

Comment: I changed it to CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT at 120000 and I am now getting a response at least though it has no response code.